# Getting an id array to pass to onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a jQuery code that parses a JSON encoded string like this:

```
 var results = JSON.parse(msg);
```

Then it does a `foreach` statement as such:

```
jQuery.each( results.stores,function(k,v){

     var store_id = v.id;


     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(v.lat,v.lng),
         icon: image,
         shadow: shadow,
         shape: shape,
         title: v.name+' : '+v.address
 });
```

I need to be able to pass the id of the item that has been clicked to the `onclick` event so it can be passed to the PHP script to do the query properly. I am guessing I will have to create a function and then make that function call inside this area.

Here is the working `onclick` function, but it will only pass the first id within the JSON string:

### Updated code

```
 $("#list li").click(function(){

 //var store_id = $(this).store_id;
 var pathname = "ajax=1&store_id="+store_id+"&action=get_nearby_stores&distance="+distance+"&lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&products="+$('#edit-products').val();

      $("#pocp_content").load("file1.php?" + pathname)
 });
```

Comment: I can't follow this explanation, your narrative seems to skip some of the most important details (what is being clicked? What results are you expecting?) Could you put a JSFiddle together, or explain more clearly? If that's just me being slow, I apologise, see if others can get it.

Comment: @Shai - Sorry - let me clarify. View this page: http://test.theslickfeed.com/index.php When someone clicks a listing, it should fire an onclick event, grab the id that they clicked on from the json pass it thru to the php file, and then php file queries the database and returns the proper data for that item clicked in the panel on the left (when opened) Notice the sql line at the top - All clicks show id='5'

Comment: whole concept of click handler is flawed....you have it set to click on whole list...should be item specific and should be getting data from the instance of item

Comment: @charlietfl - I'm much better at php than I am at jquery stuff, that's obvious. The rest of this works, it's just piecing together these two parts now. So with that said, any examples?

Comment: click on `<li>` and within click handler `this` is current element being clicked. Then look within that element for the data you need. Suggest putting all data needed on the `<li>` using `data-` attributes...then compile url from those attributes

Comment: `$("ol")` should be `$("li")` (or ideally `$("#list li")` in case you ever have a second, unrelated list on the same page). This will add the click handler to each list item rather than the list as a whole. Then you'll need to get the **store_id** from your element (refer to the element using `$(this)` within your click handler)... do you have a way of doing so? If not we can help you save each store_id into each list element for retrieval when it's clicked. Also remove your `evt.preventDefault();` (or define `evt` as the click handler function's parameter)

Comment: eh - I still don't get it! :( So I set the ol to be the #list li and while it is passing an id per say to the script - it's not the right one for the store. I think it's the list count number and not the proper store id. I've updated my code above

Comment: erm, then maybe your store_ids which you get from your "msg" i guess, is just wrong? we can't tell..

Comment: the ids are coming in from the msg just fine its figuring out from there

Comment: So frustrated! :*( I can't get this right